# I'm trying to learn Java, and I was studying the Math library

Tags: java, eclipse, math, func

So, I was trying to run this code:
I had to put the `private static double()` because it didn't run and java kept asking for me to do that

```java
public class Math {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double z = -9.8;
        double A;

        
        A = Math.abs(z);
        
        System.out.println("Valor absoluto de " + z + " = " + A);
    }

    
    private static double abs(double z) {
        
        double A = abs(z);
        
        return A;
    }
}
```

and i don't know what it's wrong, help please

please explain why do I have to do the private static and what do I have to write in it

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Are you saying that the code in the question is working as expected? Please show the code that *isn't* working and which errors you get by editing the into the question.

Comment: @Sören it isn't working and this shows up: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at math.Math.abs(Math.java:18)

Comment: You get a stack overflow because your `abs` function calls itself. It will call itself again and again, creating a new stack frame each time until the space allocated for the stack is exhausted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a slightly confusing topic, if you're new to Java.

First, you'll have to understand the concept of *objects* in computer science.

As you may know, coding languages can fall into categories referred to as *[paradigms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm)*.
*Java*, along with several others—notably, *C++*, *C#*, and *Visual Basic*—are within, what is termed an *[object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)* paradigm.

In computer science, an *[object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science))* is typically defined as follows.

> *"... an object can be a variable, a data structure, a function, or a method."*

As a note, you'll find in most Java literature, an *"object"* is in reference to a *class*, and not the variables or methods.
This is not a standard, it's just a common occurance.

Your question is regarding why you have to write *"private static"*.

The *[static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)* keyword is a context modifier for your method.
In otherwords, you're negating the need for an instance—the context is *static*, in terms of its declaration.

> *"Static methods, which have the static modifier in their declarations, should be invoked with the class name, without the need for creating an instance of the class*"

For example

```java
Example.methodName();
```

As, opposed to

```java
Example example = new Example();
example.methodName();
```

Since a class's variables and methods are within the context of a plausible instance, a static modifier will remove it from that context.
Thus, you cannot access the instance variables and methods, from within a static context.

Similar to how you can access the *Math* methods without an instance.

Consider the following.

```java
String string = "stack overflow";

static void methodName() {
    /* 'string' will be inaccessible here */
}
```

So, in conclusion, you *can* provide a static modifier to your method, to access it from within the *main* method, which is static.

Additionally, you could simply instantiate your enclosing class, and access the non-static method that way.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double z = -9.8;
    double A;
    
    Math math = new Math();
    A = math.abs(z);

    System.out.println("Valor absoluto de " + z + " = " + A);
}

private double abs(double z) {

    double A = abs(z);

    return A;
}
```

Furthermore, I believe you mean to have this written.

```java
private double abs(double z) {

    double A = java.lang.Math.abs(z);

    return A;
}
```

Comment: you were right! it worked! so the private double abs(double z) for being in a context that is static i couldn't acess the Math library? or am I wrong?

Comment: You would still be able to access the _Math_ library from within your _static_ method.  You couldn't access your method from within the _main_ method, because _main_ is static.  Similar to the example I provided, where you cannot access _string_ from within _method_.

Comment: OOOHH ok now i understand, main is also static. Nice! thank you so much for your help